# Make server connection When background and not running the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am using the regionMonitoring in my app,so didEnter and didExit methods are always being called in Background and not running State also.Now problem is I want to send the data to server at the time of regionMonitoring methods called,i am using NSURLConnection for post the data.Here I am not able to send in Not Running state,What can i do.help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of NSURLConnection, use NSURLSession and set the backgroundconfiguration.

Comment: @RJVKumar will it work in not Running state also

Comment: If you app is not running then it can't do anything because it is not running, however if it is triggered by `didEnterRegion` or `didExitRegion` then it is now running in the background

Comment: @RJVKumar so when the didEnterRegion method triggered then it will send the data to server in not running state also.

Comment: Yes, if the method is called then surely backgroundconfiguration will work.

Comment: @RJVKumar ,this is the first time i am going to use the nsurlsessions.so nsurlsessions are Asynchronous connections,if i want to send array of data server using for loop.and i want to know for which request,i got the response,how can i do this

Comment: i am using semaphores to do this,thanx